# Securing Apache Spark

Tags: security, apache-spark

I'm trying to work out how one might enforce security when running spark jobs on a shared cluster.  I understand how one can ensure unauthorised nodes cannot join the cluster (setup shared secret kerberos auth) and how one can restrict who can submit jobs (run under yarn and then use something like ranger to restrict who can access each queue).  I am however, struggling to understand how one might restrict access to resources needed by the spark job.

If I understand correctly all Spark processes on the worker nodes will run as the spark user.  Presumably the spark user itself should have pretty minimal permissions, however the question then becomes what to do if your spark job needs to access e.g. sql server. [The Spark security docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/security.html) make mention of a key store.  Does that mean that a user submitting a job can pass through a principal and keytab with spark-submit which can be used to authenticate with the external resource as if it were the submitter making the request.

A follow up question is that the security docs also mention that temporary files (shuffle files etc) are not encrypted.  Does that mean that you have to assume that any data processed by spark may be potentially leaked to any other user of your spark cluster? If so is it possible to use their proposed workaround (use an encrypted partition for this data) to solve this?  I'm assuming not as the spark user itself must have the ability to decrypt this data and all programs are runining as this user....

Comment: All that is pretty confusing. IMHO the important thing is to protect the **data** i.e. activate Kerberos authentication and ACL-based authorization to HDFS files. Ranger & Sentry just make things more complicated in practice, especially when you want to allow Pig/Spark/Sqoop access to Hive tables.

Comment: Your keystore thing is also confusing. You need to get the Kerberos ticket *before* you launch the Spark (or Sqoop) job, then the job can connect to the Hadoop keystore, retrieve dynamically whatever is stored there -- possibly a database password --, use it, then erase it from memory without leaving any trace on disk.

Comment: Hi, apologies if it's confusing.  I understand that protecting the data is important- my point is that this is somewhat compromised if spark can potentially write it to a tmp directory to which any other user of the cluster can read.

Comment: If the Spark job authenticates to HDFS as, say, `realDonald@DRUMPF` then all its temporary files will be "owned" by user `realDonald` -- and if the authorization policy is appropriate (i.e. generic HDFS umask + default ACLs on that specific directory) then nobody else should have access to these temp files. IMHO the talks about encyption-at-rest are overkill. *(Encryption of network traffic with SSL is another matter -- what happens on the ethernet does not stay on the ethernet!)*

Comment: Ah ok- so you're saying even files tmp written to local disk (from reading the spark docs it appears the default place is /tmp) will be owned by the user submitting the spark job and not user the spark slave is running as?

Comment: Why should the executors run under a different user account? *That* looks like a security breach.

Comment: AFAIK, the Spark driver authenticates to YARN with the current Kerberos ticket, then YARN creates a "delegation token" for the job, and spawns containers for the executors (with the token attached). So the executors inherit the user account and the HDFS privileges of the original Kerberos user.

Comment: apologies for not replying sooner- this actually explains it perfectly and shows how I had a mistaken assumption originally (i.e. that the executors didn't inherit the user account).  If don't think I can accept an answer in a commment, but if you want to put it as an answer I'll accept!

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to work out how one might enforce security when running
>   spark jobs on a shared cluster. I understand how one can ensure
>   unauthorised nodes cannot join the cluster (setup shared secret
>   kerberos auth) and how one can restrict who can submit jobs (run under
>   yarn and then use something like ranger to restrict who can access
>   each queue). I am however, struggling to understand how one might
>   restrict access to resources needed by the spark job.

You use YARN queue to do that. Each queue could have minimal amount of resources available for the queue. Thus, you define queue ACL to ensure that only trusted users will submit to the queue and define minimum amount of resources this queue will have.

> If I understand correctly all Spark processes on the worker nodes will
>   run as the spark user.

Your understanding is not accurate. With Kerberos enabled (which is precondition for any security discussion) Spark jobs will be executed as the Kerberos user, who launched them. There is an important caveat to the matter — Kerberos usernames must match operating system usernames.

> Presumably the spark user itself should have
>   pretty minimal permissions, however the question then becomes what to
>   do if your spark job needs to access e.g. sql server. The Spark
>   security docs make mention of a key store. Does that mean that a user
>   submitting a job can pass through a principal and keytab with
>   spark-submit which can be used to authenticate with the external
>   resource as if it were the submitter making the request.

This key store is used for a different and very specific purpose — support TLS encryption for HTTP communication (e.g. Spark UI). Thus, you can not use it as a secret storage to access third-party systems. Overall, in Hadoop infrastructure there is no way to share credentials with the job. Thus, mechanism should be reinvented every time. As jobs will be executed on OS-level on behalf of users that start them, you could rely on OS controls to distribute credentials to third-party resources (e.g. file system permissions).

> A follow up question is that the security docs also mention that
>   temporary files (shuffle files etc) are not encrypted. Does that mean
>   that you have to assume that any data processed by spark may be
>   potentially leaked to any other user of your spark cluster? If so is
>   it possible to use their proposed workaround (use an encrypted
>   partition for this data) to solve this? I'm assuming not as the spark
>   user itself must have the ability to decrypt this data and all
>   programs are runining as this user....

There couple things to note. First of all, as already mentioned, Spark job on Kerberized-cluster will be executed as a user, who started the job. All temporary files produced by the job will have file system permissions that grant access to only that specific user and yarn group (includes only yarn user). Secondly, disk encryption will protect you from disk being stolen, but will never guaranty safety for OS-level attacks. Thirdly, as of Spark 2.1 temporary files encryption is available.

If you are interested to get more in-depth understanding of Spark-on-YARN security model I would encourage you to read [Apache Spark on YARN Security Model Analysis](http://engineering.rallyhealth.com/bigdata/security/2017/04/15/apache-spark-on-yarn-security-model-analysis.html) (disclaimer I'm the author).